# How to remove or hide the google icon from the google translate

Tags: php, html

**I am using this line of code:**

```
 <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      var translator = new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'en',
      includedLanguages: 'en,zh-CN,zh-TW',

      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
   }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

**Here is the output and I want to remove the icon, how can possibly remove it? or hide**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply - No.

You cannot do this, as the Google logo is an element inside of an iframe. If it was on the same domain as yours, you could have used javascript to apply styles to that element... but if you try it now, you'll run into Cross-Domain References errors.

Besides, why would you want to remove it? You are getting a nice service for free, the owner deserves some credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi,thanks for everything..This is the correct answer**

**

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate, .goog-te-gadget-icon {
        display: none !important;
    }
    body {
        top: 0px !important;
    }
    .goog-tooltip {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .goog-tooltip:hover {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .goog-text-highlight {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        border: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot remove the logo, you can position the google translator container with CSS to hide the icon..

```
.goog-te-banner-frame {
 left: -180px !important;
}
```

But I personally would keep the google translate logo on there.